# Instructions for R package development for a layman

Tags: r, package

I have never done it, but want to develop R package for domestic use:

For example following are my functions and a data:

```
# random DNA function 
randDNA = function(n){
paste(sample(c("A", "C", "T", "G"), n, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
}
# DNA to RNA function 
dna2rna <- function(inputStr) { 
  if (!is.character(inputStr)) 
    stop("need character input") 
  is = toupper(inputStr) 
  chartr("T", "U", is) 
}

# complementary sequence function 
compSeq <-  function(inputStr){
 chartr("ACTG", "TGAC", inputStr)
 }

# example data
dnaseq1 <- c("ATTGTATCTGGGTATTTCCCTTAATTGGGGCCTTT")
dnaseq2 <- c("TGGGGTAAACCCGGTTTAAAATATATATATTTTT")
myseqdata <- data.frame(dnaseq1, dnaseq2)
save(myseqdata, file = "myseqdata.RData")
```

I tried to use utils package to develop framework, but had a problem:

```
require(utils)

package.skeleton(list = c("randDNA","dna2rna", "compSeq", "myseqdata"),  
     name = "dnatool",environment = .GlobalEnv, path = "c:", force = FALSE)



Creating directories ...
    Creating DESCRIPTION ...
    Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
    Saving functions and data ...
    Making help files ...
    Error in .find.package(pkgName, lib.loc, verbose = verbose) : 
      there is no package called 'dnatool'
    Error in package.skeleton(list = c("randDNA", "dna2rna", "compSeq", "myseqdata"),  : 
      Error in .find.package(pkgName, lib.loc, verbose = verbose) : 
      there is no package called 'dnatool'
```

I have question regarding why I am getting this error. When I looked at C:\dnatool I can see the folder created with the data and r functions.

Now I want to compile to make it as package. As I am reading instructions, I used command prompt to pack it: I am using Windows 7.

```
c:\> R CMD build dnatool
```

Obviously does not work. Is that due to above problem? What path should I be in? Where there is R exe or C: or c:\dnatool

I will appreciate your help, if you can in R "layman" style help...thanks...

EDITS:
I downloaded  Rtools Rtools212.exe for R version 2.12.2 from:
http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/
The tools are installed in C:\Rtools

```
Directory of c:\Rtools

09/18/2011  08:08 AM    <DIR>          .
09/18/2011  08:08 AM    <DIR>          ..
09/18/2011  08:07 AM    <DIR>          bin
03/31/2010  09:50 AM            18,347 COPYING
09/18/2011  08:08 AM    <DIR>          MinGW
09/18/2011  08:09 AM    <DIR>          MinGW64
10/04/2010  10:21 AM             1,836 README.txt
10/07/2010  08:26 AM             3,676 Rtools.txt
09/18/2011  08:10 AM           728,889 unins000.dat
09/18/2011  08:07 AM         1,182,143 unins000.exe
               5 File(s)      1,934,891 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  36,454,875,136 bytes free
```

My skeleton of the package is in C:\dnatool:

```
 Directory of c:\dnatool

09/17/2011  11:14 PM    <DIR>          .
09/17/2011  11:14 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/17/2011  11:14 PM    <DIR>          data
09/17/2011  11:14 PM               304 DESCRIPTION
09/17/2011  11:14 PM    <DIR>          man
09/17/2011  11:14 PM    <DIR>          R
09/17/2011  11:14 PM               385 Read-and-delete-me
               2 File(s)            689 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  36,455,153,664 bytes free
```

My R program is C:\R....

My confusion is on the following instructions: where should execute them? I believe in command prompt. Under which directory?

```
* Run R CMD build to build the package tarball.
* Run R CMD check to check the package tarball.
```

************Edits2: partial solution but with new error ******************************
The first round of problem has been solved with the suggestion for path. I have to manually change the path to:

```
C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\perl\bin;C:\Rtools\MinGW\bin;
   C:\Program files\R\R-2.12.2\bin\x64;
```

I stored the skeleton to new directory. By running the following command in command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Documents\rpackages> Rcmd INSTALL --build dnatool

* installing to library 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-212~1.2/library'
* installing *source* package 'dnatool' ...
** R
** data
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
Warning: C:/Users/Owner/Documents/rpackages/dnatool/man/dnatool-package.Rd:34: A
ll text must be in a section
Warning: C:/Users/Owner/Documents/rpackages/dnatool/man/dnatool-package.Rd:35: A
ll text must be in a section
*** installing help indices
Error in Rd_info(db[[i]]) : Rd files must have a non-empty \title.
See chapter 'Writing R documentation' in manual 'Writing R Extensions'.
* removing 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-212~1.2/library/dnatool
```

I was unsuccessful to create the package, the see the error in above window. What does this mean. I added relevent information line 34 and 35 of the file dnatool-package 
   .Rd ...help ...thanks...

Comment: IIRC, you have to remember to set the path. Older versions of RTools didn't do this for you, you had to do it manually. Not sure if that's still the case.

Comment: how and where I set the path?

Comment: please see my new edits on Rtools and other information.

Comment: INSTALL is giving you clear instructions on the problems in your .Rd files, and suggests you read the extensions manual. Otherwise, I get exactly the same as you in R-devel a r56992 nd Rtools 2.13. Your question has way too much useless information in it now if your actual problem is just that you need to edit your Rd files so that they have \titles{}.

Comment: I suggest you try generating a default .Rd file and see if it compiles. If it does, there's something wrong with your changed .Rd file (including encoding). To individually make sure your .Rd file compiles fine, you can use `R CMD Rd2txt filename.Rd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my question myself, so that it will remain unanswered, if fact partially it is. With the suggestions here , the problem has been solved by changing path by setting the following:

```
C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\perl\bin;C:\Rtools\MinGW\bin;
   C:\Program files\R\R-2.12.2\bin\x64;
I stored the skeleton to new directory.
```

By running the following command in command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Documents\rpackages> Rcmd INSTALL --build dnatool
```